# Constrained minimization of a continuous and coercive function

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

A continuous and coercive function $g: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has at least one minimizer over $\mathbb{R}$.

When is it guaranteed that the constrained problem $\underset{x \in \Omega}{\min} g(x)$ also has at least one solution? Is it enough that $\Omega$ is closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's sufficient. If $\Omega $ is bounded and closed, it is also compact, by the Heine Borel theorem, and since it is continuous it attains it's minimum and maximum.

If $\Omega $ is closed not necessarily bounded then you can reduce the question to the case of a bounded domain by coercivity: there is some $R>0$ such that $g(x)> g(x_0)$ for some $x_0$ with $|x_0|\le R$ and every $x $ such that $|x|>R$, so you can minimize in $\Omega\cap \overline {B_R(0)}$, which is also closed

Comment: Great, thank you for showing how a coercive $g$ leads to a bounded $\Omega$!